# How big can a "personal item" be on an Asiana flight

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, asiana-airlines

Basically, I have both a Costco carry-on and a Timbuk2 backpack. I will be on a flight from LAX-ICN-SGN.

[Asiana says](https://us.flyasiana.com/C/en/homepage.do?menuId=003006003001000&menuType=CMS) on its website that they allow one carry on and a personal item. I know the dimensions and weight already.

My Costco Kirkland 21½-in carry-on has total linear dimensions under the limit by about ½ in. I wonder if my Timbuk2 Command backpack would be considered as a personal item or if it would also count as carry on.

On a side note: if both are allowed, do both have to be total below 22lb, or is that limit just for carry-ons? I ask because I want to carry a gadget in my backpack.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, that's pretty borderline, your "personal item" is supposed to be an item (laptop, book, etc) and not a backpack.

In practice, though, I always travel with a rollaboard bag and a small backpack.  Aside from the extreme LCC fringe (Ryanair, EasyJet, Tiger etc), I have *never* been questioned about this, and that includes a dozen or so flights on Asiana.  I do make a point of keeping the backpack pretty flat, and in a pinch the rollaboard does extend enough to pack it in if needed.

The weight limit is for your "primary" carryon item only, and is intended to ensure that it's not going to break the baggage compartment or kill someone if it falls out.